# method-override module not working in es6

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, x-http-method-override

I am trying to override the request method for my URL. But the module I found in express which is method-override doesn't work using es6 notation at least not for me. the error I get is a syntax error this is a commonjs module etcetera.

I tried to import it like this.

```
import { MethodOverride } from 'method-override';
```

But the editor suggests to auto-fill (intellisense):

```
import { MethodOverrideOptions } from 'method-override';
```

but this is not working, any suggestions or tips to fix this?

Comment: Did you try require? const MethodOverride = require("method-override")

Comment: i know it works. but it's not ES6 so i can not use it